# Checking if Array Is Empty In A Google Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome-extension

In this code block I am using an if else statement to check to see if an array is empty. The array is being populated from the local storage. If the array is empty I am displaying a message that says,

```
 $('#alert').html("<strong>Nothing to hide!</strong> Add some keywords that you hate!");
```

If the array has keywords stored inside it, then I want to display the keywords instead.

The problem is after adding keywords it displays the message for when the array is empty and it shows the keywords. This continues to happen till I close the extension and reopen it.

My question is could this be because it is an extension? It appears my code is correct because it works when I open the page again. But why does it not work when the function is run?

How can I fix this? being that this is a google chrome extension.

```
// This function populates the keywords to the view
function loadKeyWords() {
    $('#keyWords').html('');
    localArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyWords'));
    if (localArray.length === 0) {
        $('#alert').html("<strong>Nothing to hide!</strong> Add some keywords that you hate!");
        // $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
        return false;
    } else {
        //send data
        for(var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
            $('#keyWords').prepend('<li><input class="check" name="check" type="checkbox">'+localArray[i]+'</li>'); 
            $( "div:contains("+localArray[i]+")" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $( "section:contains("+localArray[i]+")" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $('#nav-1').fadeIn(550);
        }
        return localArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors in console when doing this? parser returns objects, and also, your **localArray** variable is global. It will hold previous data if error happens on parser (empty string? ... or no array length?)

Comment: Seeing both your message and the keywords makes it sound like you're forgetting to remove the `$('#alert')` message.  Could it be as simple as that?